# What are drawbacks of setting REPLICA IDENTITY FULL in PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, replication, change-data-capture

I want to use the wal2json extension to capture the changes in the PostgreSQL database. 
I need to find the diff between old and new rows. 
Having searched the Internet for an answer, I realized that this can be achieved by setting the REPLICA IDENTITY FULL option on the table of interest.

I think this is exactly what I need, but I wonder are there any significant drawbacks of this setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only disadvantage is that it will produce more data than are necessary to identify the affected row, but since that is what you want, it is not a disadvantage to you.